# Check if Ip is blocked and redirect user to 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net mvc 4.

Also I have a UserBaseController which is inherited from Controller.
In OnActionExecuting I am checking if the ip is blocked.
If ip is blocked I want to show user 404 page with html.
But when I do redirect it gets into infinite redirects loop. What is the correct way to show the 404 page?

Comment: Also I tried to google it, but everything has failed for me

Comment: Does your 404 page perform any check on IP ? It should not.

Comment: only check for ip is in userbasecontroller. there is error controller for 404 page but it doesn't inherit from userbasecontroller